# How to increment an associative array in Bash

Tags: arrays, bash

I have this associative array:

```
lettres['A']=0
…(from 'A' to 'Z')…
lettres['Z']=0
```

My question is simple: How to take the value of one element and increment it? I have tried the following:

```
lettres[$char]=${lettres[$char]}++
```

But it fails, as the result is «0++++++++». How can I easily increment the value?

EDIT: More code:

```
while (( i++ < ${#word} )); do
    #$char current char
    char=$(expr substr "$word" $i 1)
    if [[ "${mot[@]}" =~ "${char} " || "${mot[${#mot[@]}-1]}" == "${char}" ]]; then
        #char is currently in array $mot -> skipping
        echo 'SKIPPING'
    else
        #Char is not in array $mot -> adding + incrementing lettres
        ((lettres[char]++))
        echo ${lettres[$char]}
        #Adding to $mot
        mot[${#mot[@]}]=$char
    fi
    echo "<$char>"
done
```

Comment: Instead of saying "Nope, doesn't work..." and then posting some code without further comment, make a runnable test case, point to the relevant lines, say what you tried, what happens, and what you expected to happen. E.g. "lettres[F] is 3 on this line. I tried your suggestion on the next line here, but afterwards, it's still 3 while I expected it to be 4"

Answer (score 9):

Using bash version 4 and up, this would work:

```
$ declare -A lettres
$ char=B
$ ((lettres[$char]++))
$ echo "${lettres['A']}"
0
$ echo "${lettres['B']}"
1
```

The `(( ))` force an [arithmetic context](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression), in which you can increment the value of the array element. Note that it is also [recommended to use `declare -A`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays) to guarantee maximum backward compatibility with standard indexed arrays.